# C# Forms - Can't drag files from Windows Explorer search onto RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, windows-explorer

The drag part of my code is as follows:

```
  private void richTextBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
  }
```

I am using Win10-64bit with 12GB RAM and I have 50,000 .eml files in 500 subdirectories.  If I navigate directly into one of those subdirectories using Windows Explorer and select one of more of the 100 files it contains I can drag/drop them onto a RichTextBox in my application or to my desktop and all is well.  It also works for both if I do a search of just one subdirectory from its parent using Windows Explorer and drag from the resulting list of about 100 files.

However, if I do a recursive search for these files from the parent directory of several of these subdirectories using Windows Explorer and get a list of 5,000 or even 50,000 files, if I try to drag even one file from the resulting list it still works perfectly to the desktop but when I drag over the RichTextBox the Copy effect does not display.  Instead I just get the circle with a slash through it.  I've put a breakpoint on the DragDropEffects.Copy line and it does reach that line.

What's strange to me is that I can drag from that search list to the desktop perfectly fine, including all 50,000 files.  I know I can implement a transversal of all the individual directories in my code but the drag-drop approach is what I would prefer for my needs. Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not at all clear what the problem or question is.  That code simply tells Windows which cursor to use, nothing more.  Note that even with a file DnD the actual file is not on the clipboard, just the file name(s)

Comment: @Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp - I know that the code simply tells Windows which cursor to use and nothing more. 
 To make the issue real concise, why, when there are many files, isn't the cursor that I've specified being displayed over the RichTextBox when it is over the desktop?

Comment: "I've put a breakpoint on the DragDropEffects.Copy line and it does reach that line." - Inspect `e.Data.GetFormats()` to see all the formats available.  You often have to allow for multiple formats.

Comment: With multiple files, I've noticed that a number of programs simply set the cursor based on the first one.  Inspecting all of them, especially 50k files, may take too long.